# CKEditor - filter html without creating an editor instance

Tags: filter, ckeditor

Is there a way to do something like `CKEditor.filter('some html');` ?
How can I create a `filter` instance with the default rules and then use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. All you got to do is to combine [CKEDITOR.htmlParser](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlParser) and [CKEDITOR.filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter):

```
function gimmeFilter( rules ) {
    var filter = new CKEDITOR.filter( rules ),
        writer = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.basicWriter();

    var fn = function( input, output, msg ) {
        var fragment = CKEDITOR.htmlParser.fragment.fromHtml( input );
        writer.reset();

        filter.applyTo( fragment );
        fragment.writeHtml( writer );
        return writer.getHtml();
    };

    fn.allow = function( rules ) {
        filter.allow( rules );
    };

    return fn;
}

var f = gimmeFilter( {
    'p b i': {
        classes: 'foo',
        styles: 'text-align'
    }
} );

f( '<p style="text-align:right"><b class="boom" style="color: red">foo</b> <i class="foo">bar</i> <u>bum</u></p>' );
>>> "<p style="text-align:right"><b>foo</b> <i class="foo">bar</i> bum</p>"
```

See that `<u>` tag, `style="color: red"` and `class="boom"` are gone.

Comment: Thank you! But I am looking for a way to get the same rules of my editor without creating one. So I can do something like: `var f = gimmeFilter(CKEDITOR.getAutomaticModeRules());`.

Comment: You don't need any instance created to have the above code working. However, if you need to know default rules for an instance, see `CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.filter.allowedContent`.

Comment: `CKEDITOR.instances.instanceName.filter.allowedContent` is generated by `filter.allow`, and cannot be pass to the constructor directly. Is there's a way to get the raw rules or convert `filter.allowedContent` to the raw rules?

Comment: Hm... But you're trying to clone filter? If you just want to reuse the `editor.filter`, you don't need to do that. Although, cloning should not be too complicated - you'd need to translate `filter.allowedContent` to the raw format and they are very similar (if not identical).

Comment: @TrantorLiu did you get this working? I am trying to do the same thing?